# Как включить в скомпилированный код процедуры которые в нем явно не используются?

Tags: delphi

Есть ли какая-то директива компилятора, поставив которую в возле процедуры позволит эту процедуру включить в файл exe? Процедуру не использую, а адрес её - да, и адрес сам вычисляется. Т.е прямой ссылки на нее нет в модулях. Знаю что можно просто её после exit поставить или через if сделать, но мне такое не нравится.

Comment: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Optimization_(Delphi)

Comment: Это попытка сделать хитрую защиту/самомодифицирующийся код?

Comment: @KoVadim
генератор кода да и прокладные  вставки

Comment: а что такое "прокладные вставки"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702033/compile-link-unused-functions-procedures-in-delphi